# Issues dynamically creating buttons with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, calculator

I'm attempting to dynamically add operator buttons to my calculator however I'm just not having any luck. I've created functions to dynamically create the number and operator buttons. The numbers have been created successfully but once I try to add in the operators, nothing happens. I'm attempting to add the operators in between my parentheses buttons and the evaluate button using a for-in loop. It seems when I create the evaluate button before the operators, the evaluate button is created successfully yet the operators aren't. If I shift the code to create the operators  *before* the evaluate button, neither are appearing. I'm fairly certain the issue lies within my for-in loop but I'm not quite sure where. Any and all help/guidance is greatly appreciated!

```
 var opsData = {
  add: {
    precedence: 1,
    name: 'add',
    operation: function (a, b) {return a + b;},
    output: function (a, b) {return a + ' + ' + b;},
    buttonHTML: '+'
  },
  subtract: {
    precedence: 1,
    name: 'subtract',
    operation: function (a, b) {return a - b;},
    output: function (a, b) {return a + ' - ' + b;},
    buttonHTML: '-'
  },
  multiply: {
    precedence: 2,
    name: 'multiply',
    operation: function (a, b) {return a * b;},
    output: function (a, b) {return a + ' * ' + b;},
    buttonHTML: '*'
  },
  divide: {
    precedence: 2,
    name: 'divide',
    operation: function (a, b) {return a / b;},
    isInvalidInput: function (a, b) {return b == 0 ? 'division by 0' : false;},
    output: function (a, b) {return a + ' / ' + b;},
    buttonHTML: '/'
  }
}

$.fn.addButton = function(html, className, onclick) {
  $('<button />', {
    html: html,
    'class': 'button ' + className,
    click: onclick
    }).appendTo(this);
  return this;
}

var addOperatorButton = function(op, click) {
  $operators.addButton(op.buttonHTML, 'operator ' + op.name, function(e) {
    click.call(this, e);
    $currentCalc.text(inputStack.getCalculationString());
    $collapsedCalc.text(inputStack.getCalculationString(true));
    $input.text(inputStackgetPartialResult());
    $input.data({clearOnInput: true});
  });
};

var getInput = () => {
  var input = $input.text();
  return input.match(/error/i) ? 0 : parseFloat($input.text())
}

for (var i in opsData) {
  (function(i) {
    if (!opsData.buttonHTML[i]) return;
    addOperatorButton(opsData[i], () => {
      inputStack.push(getInput(), new Operation(opsData[i]));
    })
  }(i))
}
```

The link to my full codepen is here: https://codepen.io/tazmancooks/pen/PoNwGMX

Apologies if my issue isn't articulated well, I'm still fairly new to jQuery and Javascript in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is when you are trying to loop through the opsData object.

```
for (var i in opsData) {
  (function(i) {
    if (!opsData.buttonHTML[i]) return;
      addOperatorButton(opsData[i], () => {
      inputStack.push(getInput(), new Operation(opsData[i]));
    })
  }(i))
}
```

You are accessing the [i] property of buttonHTML when you should be accessing opsData[i].buttonHTML

Answer (score 2):

You accessed the `opsData` object wrong: change `if (!opsData.buttonHTML[i]) return;` to `if (!opsData[i].buttonHTML) return;` in ***line 352***

The buttons are there now, but you need to change the CSS still.

```js
$(function() {

  var opsData = {
    add: {
      precedence: 1,
      name: 'add',
      operation: function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
      },
      output: function(a, b) {
        return a + ' + ' + b;
      },
      buttonHTML: '+'
    },
    subtract: {
      precedence: 1,
      name: 'subtract',
      operation: function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
      },
      output: function(a, b) {
        return a + ' - ' + b;
      },
      buttonHTML: '-'
    },
    multiply: {
      precedence: 2,
      name: 'multiply',
      operation: function(a, b) {
        return a * b;
      },
      output: function(a, b) {
        return a + ' * ' + b;
      },
      buttonHTML: '*'
    },
    divide: {
      precedence: 2,
      name: 'divide',
      operation: function(a, b) {
        return a / b;
      },
      isInvalidInput: function(a, b) {
        return b == 0 ? 'division by 0' : false;
      },
      output: function(a, b) {
        return a + ' / ' + b;
      },
      buttonHTML: '/'
    }
  }

  var Operation = function(options) {
    var inputs = [];

    for (var key in options) {
      this[key] = options[key];
    };

    //Check if another input is needed, if not push current input to inputs array
    this.addInput = function(input) {
      if (this.isSaturated) return this;
      inputs.push(input)
      return this;
    }

    this.invalidInput = this.invalidInput || function() {
      return false;
    };

    //Check if operation already has all needed inputs
    this.isSaturated = () => {
      var inputCount = this.singleinput ? 1 : 2
      for (var i = 0; i < inputCount; i++) {
        if (inputs[i] === null || isNaN(inputs[i])) return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

    this.execute = () => {
      //If error is thrown, return
      if (this.error) return this;

      //Check if inputs are missing OR if operation was already executed
      if (!this.isSaturated || this.value != null) return this;

      //Map inputs to numerical values since inputs can also be operational objects [addition(1, multiplication(2, 3))]
      var inputValues = inputs.map(function(input) {
        return Number(input);
      });

      //Throw an error if there is invalid input
      this.error = this.isInvalidInput.apply(this, inputValues);
      if (this.error) {
        throw new Error(this.error);
      }

      this.calculationString = this.getCalculationString();
      this.value = this.operation.apply(this, inputValues);
      return this

    }

    this.getCalculationString = function(lastInput, collapsed) {
      if (collapsed) {
        this.execute();
        if (this.value != null) return this.value.toString();
      }

      var singleInput = this.singleInput;

      //Maps inputs to a string
      var inputValues = inputs.map(function(input) {
        var inputValue = input.getCalculationString ?
          input.getCalculationString(lastInput, collapsed) :
          input.toString();

        //Remove parenthases from any single input operations
        return singleInput ? inputValue.replace(/^\((.*)\)$/g, '$1') : inputValue;
      });
      return options.output.apply(this, inputValues.concat([lastInput]))
    }

    // Translate numerical value of the operation result
    // Execute operation if no result yet
    this.valueOf = () => {
      if (this.value == null) {
        this.execute()
      }
      return this.value
    }

    this.toString = () => {
      if (this.getCalculationString == null) {
        this.execute();
      }
      return this.getCalculationString();
    }

    var inputStack = (function() {
      var levels;

      var closedContext;

      var partialResult;

      var error;

      var Stack = function() {
        this.peek = function() {
          return this[this.length - 1];
        }
      };
      Stack.prototype = [];

      var reset = function() {
        levels = new Stack;
        levels.push(new Stack);
        closedContext = error = null
      };

      var wrapLastOperation = function(operation) {
        var stack = levels.peek();
        stack.push(operation.addInput(stack.pop()))
        collapse(operation.precedence)
      };

      var collapse = function(precedence) {
        var stack = levels.peek();
        var currentOperation = stack.pop();
        var previousOperation = stack.peek()

        if (!currentOperation) return;

        if (!currentOperation.isSaturated()) {
          stack.push(currentOperation);
          return;

          try {
            partialResult = Number(currentOperation);
          } catch (e) {
            partialResult = error = 'Error: ' + e.message;
          };

          if (previousOperation && previousOperation.precedence >= precedence) {
            previousOperation.addInput(currentOperation);
            collapse(precedence);
          } else {
            stack.push(currentOperation);
          }
        }
      };

      reset();

      return {
        push: function(number, operation) {
          //If an error already exists, reset
          error && reset();

          var stack = levels.peek();
          var lastOperation = stack.peek();

          var input = closedContext || number;
          closedContext = null

          partialResult = Number(input);

          if (!lastOperation || operation.precedence > lastoperation.precedence) {
            stack.push(operation.addInput(input))

            collapse(operation.precedence)
          } else {
            lastOperation.addInput(input);
            collapse(operation.precedence);
            wrapLastOperation(operation);
          }
          return this;
        },
        openContext: function() {
          error && reset();

          var lastOperation = levels.peek().peek();

          if (closedContext || lastOperation && lastOperation.isSaturated()) return

          //Opening new context means creating a new level to the stack
          levels.push(new Stack);

          return this;
        },
        closeContext: function(number) {
          error && reset();

          //If there's only one level, there's no need to close the context.
          if (levels.length <= 1) return;

          var inpute = closedContext || number

          //Grab last used operation
          var stack = levels.peek();
          var lastOperation = stack.peek()

          closedContext = new Operation(operationData.context).addInput(
            lastOperation ? (function() {
              lastOperation.addInput(input);
              collapse(0);
              return stack.pop();
            }()) :
            input
          )

          partialResult = Number(closedContext);

          levels.pop();
          return this;
        },
        evaluate: function(number) {
          error && reset();

          var input = closedContext || number

          //If no operator provided (just a number & '='), set result to the number.
          partialResult = Number(input);

          //If '=' is used without closing all parenthases, close the context.
          while (levels.length > 1) {
            this.closeContext(input)

            var lastOperation = levels.peek().peek();
            lastOperation && lastOperation.addInput(input);

            collapse(0);
            reset();

            return this;
          }
        },
        getPartialResult: function() {
          var _partialResult = partialResult;
          partialResult = 0;
          return _partialResult
        },
        getCalculationString: function(collapsed) {
          var result = closedContext ? closedContext.getCalculationString('', collapsed) : '';

          for (var i = levels.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (var j = levels[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
              result = levels[i][j].getCalculationString(result, collapsed);
            }
            if (i > 0) {
              result = '(' + result;
            }
          }
          return result
        }
      }
    })

  }

  //Build calculator interface

  //Prototype for adding buttons
  $.fn.addButton = function(html, className, onclick) {
    $('<button />', {
      html: html,
      'class': 'button ' + className,
      click: onclick
    }).appendTo(this);
    return this;
  }

  var addNumberButton = function(num) {
    $numbers.addButton(num, 'number ' + (num === '.' ? 'dot' : 'number-' + num), () => {
      if ($input.text().match(/\./) && num == '.') return;
      if ($input.text() == 0 && num != '.' || $input.data('clearOnInput')) {
        $input.text('');
      }
      $input.data({
        clearOnInput: false
      });
      $input.text($input.text() + $(this).text());
    })
  };

  var addOperatorButton = function(op, click) {
    $operators.addButton(op.buttonHTML, 'operator ' + op.name, function(e) {
      click.call(this, e);
      $currentCalc.text(inputStack.getCalculationString());
      $collapsedCalc.text(inputStack.getCalculationString(true));
      $input.text(inputStackgetPartialResult());
      $input.data({
        clearOnInput: true
      });
    });
  };

  var getInput = () => {
    var input = $input.text();
    return input.match(/error/i) ? 0 : parseFloat($input.text())
  }

  var $calculator = $('#calculator');
  var $calcDisplay = $('<div/>', {
    'class': 'calcDisplay'
  }).appendTo($calculator);
  var $currentCalc = $('<div/>', {
    'class': 'currentCalc'
  }).appendTo($calcDisplay);
  var $collapsedCalc = $('<div/>', {
    'class': 'collapsedCalc'
  }).appendTo($calcDisplay);
  var $input = $('<div/>', {
    'class': 'input'
  }).appendTo($calcDisplay);
  var $numbers = $('<div/>', {
    'class': 'numbers'
  }).appendTo($calculator);
  var $operators = $('<div/>', {
    'class': 'operators'
  }).appendTo($calculator);

  $numbers.addButton('del', 'del', () => {
    $input.text($input.text().replace(/.$/, ''))
  })

  $numbers.addButton('CE', 'clear-entry', () => {
    $input.text('0')
  })

  $numbers.addButton('C', 'clear')

  $.each('7894561230.'.split(''), (itm, value) => {
    addNumberButton(value)
  });

  addOperatorButton({
    buttonHTML: '(',
    name: 'openContext'
  }, () => {
    inputStack.openContext();
  });

  addOperatorButton({
    buttonHTML: ')',
    name: 'closeContext'
  }, () => {
    inputStack.closeContext(getInput());
  });


  for (var i in opsData) {
    (function(i) {
      if (!opsData[i].buttonHTML) return;
      addOperatorButton(opsData[i], () => {
        inputStack.push(getInput(), new Operation(opsData[i]));
      })
    }(i))
  }

  addOperatorButton({
    buttonHTML: '=',
    name: 'evaluate'
  }, () => {
    inputStack.evaluate(getInput());
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#calculator {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 250px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2em;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.calcDisplay {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: hide;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

.button {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  margin: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.number {
  background: #fff;
}

.number-0 {
  width: 129px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='calculator'></div>
```